# Ng-show will not update when ng-click is inside div

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click, ng-show

I have a DIV with ng-show.

1. When I run ng-click on an element outside of the DIV, it works fine and I can hide it.
2. When I run ng-click on an element inside of the DIV, it does not work. I can see the variable beeing changed when i console.log it, but the view will not update.
3. I have tried to use $scope.$apply() but it gets an error and says it is already running $apply().

Parts of controller:

```
    $scope.selectedActivity = {
        "dayNr": 0,
        "actNr": 0
    };

    $scope.resetSelectedActivity = function () {
        console.log("SelAct: ", $scope.selectedActivity);
        $scope.selectedActivity.dayNr = -1;
        $scope.selectedActivity.actNr = -1;
        console.log("SelAct: ", $scope.selectedActivity);
    };

    $scope.setSelectedActivity = function (dayNr, actNr) {
        console.log("SelAct: ", $scope.selectedActivity);
        $scope.selectedActivity.dayNr = dayNr;
        $scope.selectedActivity.actNr = actNr;
        console.log("SelAct: ", $scope.selectedActivity);
    };
```

Parts of HTML:

```
    <div ng-repeat="x in xs">
            <ion-scroll>
                <div ng-repeat="y in ys track by $index">

                    <div ng-click="setSelectedActivity($parent.$index, $index)">
                        <!--THE PROBLEM IS HERE-->
                        <div ng-show="selectedActivity.dayNr == $parent.$index && selectedActivity.actNr == $index">

                            <div>
                                <!--THIS LOGS OUT CORRECT VALUES BUT NG-SHOW IS NOT UPDATED-->
                                <div ng-click="resetSelectedActivity()">
                                    Reset
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="img/checkButtonOverlay.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--THIS LOGS OUT CORRECT VALUES AND NG-SHOW _IS_ UPDATED-->
                    <button ng-click="resetSelectedActivity()">reset</button>
                </div>
            </ion-scroll>
        </div>
```

Please note that i have removed A LOT from the code because of confidentiality, but the principle should be the same.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like $apply() would have helped, but I dont know how I can run it when its already running.

Comment: according to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat ngRepeat creates a new scope, so I guess when you update the variable it's only updated in the childscope

Comment: No. Thats not it unfortunately. I tried to see what parent and child printed, but it does not make a difference.

Comment: I had removed a little too much of the code. I put the correct code in the post in the last edit. Thanks for answering. :)

Comment: @klskl not in this case because of prototypal inheritance and the fact that he shares objects instead of simple properties. Have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/1251861

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem!

I had a ng-click that showed the DIV outside. When I clicked both ng-clicks got entered.

So First resetSelectedActivity() and then it got set again in setSelectedActivity().

Fixed it using:

```
<div ng-click="resetSelectedActivity($parent.$index, $index, $event)">
    ...
</div>
```

and:

```
$scope.setSelectedActivity = function (dayNr, actNr, event) {
    $scope.selectedActivity.dayNr = dayNr;
    $scope.selectedActivity.actNr = actNr;

    //This cancel the mouseclick
    event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Comment: your `$event` is a javascript object, not related to angular. You should rather name it `event`. It's less confusing

Comment: Got the code from another stack overflow post, but good point. I agree. :)

Comment: That's was excactly the problem, the event propagates like you can see in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abidibo/Lfcsao0h/

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippee: It is actually called $event in AngularJs. It's the same object, just another way of getting it:

In ng-click you can send $event as parameter like this and it will get the javascript event:
`<div ng-click="testFunction($event)">
            Test
        </div>`

Comment: Found out that I did'nt need to send $event in ng-click. It works without the parameter. Just `event.stopPropagation();`